# Difference between iOS SDK and Framework?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am a newbie to the iOS and cocoa touch development i would like to know exact difference between and SDK and framework. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**SDK** -> it is using for developing application

**framework** -> it is present inside the SDK to make your code easy,to access device properties..etc

This both is very important to develop app.